# How to view in full screen when codeceptjs pressKey fails?

Tags: zooming, codeceptjs

I am opening a PDF file in browser and I need to switch the view to Full Screen before proceeding. I have tried `I.pressKey('F11')` and even `I.pressKey(['Control','+'])` but nothing seems to work.

Are there any updated fixes for this? Or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer/#resizewindow) you could use `resizeWindow` to achieve it.

```
I.resizeWindow(width, height)
```

Where `width` and `height` are numbers of given pixels, where `width` can be set to `maximize`.

I don't know wich driver you are using but if it is Puppeteer you should be aware that:

> Unlike other drivers Puppeteer changes the size of a viewport, not the
>   window! Puppeteer does not control the window of a browser so it can't
>   adjust its real size. It also can't maximize a window.